# Matlab - implay's default size window

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using **implay** to play some frames i want, the thing is that window size that pops is a bit small,so the user must maximize it by himself, is there any way to control the size of the window that pops up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah here we go:

```
implay(Diff);
set(findall(0,'tag','spcui_scope_framework'),'position',[150 150 700 550]);
```

Works in 2012b.
(Note: if you have more than one implay window open, this will set them all to the same size)

So you can learn how to find this kind of stuff for yourself, what I did was start with a workspace with no other open windows.

I then used `implay(Diff)` to open an implay window.

I then used `findall(0)` to find all of the figure/uicontrol handles under 0, which is the root workspace. But there were too many! Most of them are the subcomponents of the `implay` window - the menus, buttons, etc. So, I only needed the first component which was created by the root workspace.

To get this, I used `findall(0,'Parent',0);` - I could alternatively have used `allchild(0);`.

I assigned a variable to this: `ImplayHandle=findall(0,'Parent',0);`

And looked at its properties:

`get(ImplayHandle);`

Looking through these, the `Tag` seemed to be an identifier of the window, `'spcui_scope_framework'`. I also noticed the `Position` property had a similar size to that of a figure window, which was promising.

So, to check, I tried `findall(0,'Tag','spcui_scope_framework');` and I was able to see that only a single handle was returned (none of the subcomponents or menu items were also labelled with the same Tag, which was a possibility).

Finally, I closed the open window, then opened a new window using `implay(Diff);` again. I used the `set` command to try to change the window size:

`set(findall(0,'tag','spcui_scope_framework'),'position',[150 150 700 550]);`

And saw that the window size had indeed changed, as hoped.

Answer (score 1):

```
handle = implay(movie);
handle.Parent.Position = [100 100 700 550];
```

Also works if you want to set window size.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the size of a figure using `'Position'` property.
This property expect a 4-element vector in the format `[fromX fromY width height]`, thus, by changing the `width` and `height` you can control the size of the figure.

For example

```
figure( 'Position', [150 150 700 550] )
```

Opens a new figure with width of 700 pixels and height of 550 pixels.

Comment: hey mate, i tried figure(implay(Diff),'Position', [150 150 700 550]) but i am getting error that says i am using too many arguments, i also tried implay(Diff,'Position', [150 150 700 550]) and that didnt work neither

Comment: it seems that implay opens a figure by itself.However is there the option of 'Position' like is on figure? Diff is the array i use to save my frames

Comment: Try using `implay(Diff);` then 
`set(gcf,'Position', [150 150 700 550]);`. Or maybe, `figure( 'Position', [150 150 700 550] );` then `implay(Diff)`

Comment: @HughNolan - does not seems to work the figure of `implay` seems to be something different that a "figure" :(

Answer (score 0):

If one want to maximize the window, the following code works for me (windows10, matlab R2020b).

```
handle = implay('Path of the movie');
handle.Parent.WindowState= 'maximized' ;
```