# Add subplot to implay() figure

Tags: matlab, image-processing, playback

I'm trying to add a subplot to an [`implay()`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/implay.html) figure.
Or the other way around, a playable image sequence to a plot.

When i'm doing

```
subplot(1,2,1)
implay(v)
```

Matlab opens a new figure for `implay()`.

When i'm doing

```
implay(v)
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(1:10)
```

Matlab adds a subplot, but removes the video from the figure

I'm aware of creating a simple "image player" by just plotting image over image and adjusting the framerate by the use of `pause()`, but i would rather like to stay with `implay()` because of its features.

Do i miss the obvious? Anybody see a possibility (official or hack) to achieve that?

(In case it helps, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521681/matlab-implays-default-size-window/17528662#17528662) shows how to get the video figure handle: `findall(0,'tag','spcui_scope_framework')`)

Comment: you considered to use the `figure` argument ?

Comment: What do you mean?  
There is no way to pass an argument `'figure'` to neither `implay()`, `subplot()` nor `plot()`

Comment: http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/argument.html

Comment: sorry for this confuson, i mean to create a figure before execute `implay()` function, like `figure, implay()`

Comment: Ah ok, that doesnt work. Thanks though.